# Format url to friendly url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I try to format my url to friendly url by using htaccess

This is my url

> http://localhost/index.php?go=product&id=32

I'm using REQUEST METHOD

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
//Do some thing with php code to get info product from Mysql
$Title = $row['title'];
//Example: Computer 4GB 2CPU
```

But when I want to SEO my website, it's not good, I wish my url like this:

> http://localhost/product/32/Computer-4GB-2CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your .htaccess, add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?go=$1&id=$2&product=$3 [NC,L]
```

In your `<head>` add the following:

```
<base href="/">
```

So that the images and CSS work.

Add a get method for product to get the name, it should work, if it doesn't go ahead and comment.

Comment: it can not see css,js,img. I'm formating like `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?go=product&id=$2`  it's work but it look so bad

Comment: @CaoHữuThànhHuy I edited the answer above, refer to what is below that .htaccess content. Please click the checkmark if I helped you.

Comment: It's look good if look like `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?go=product&id=$2 [NC,L]` . I edit and it's work, thank you

Comment: @CaoHữuThànhHuy Great! I wish you the best of luck on your project!